# SharePoint 2010 Breadcrumb behavior when editing layouts.sitemap

Tags: breadcrumb

I am using application pages inside SharePoint 2010 used to create users and roles for my ClaimsBasedAuthentication (pages come from http://fba.codeplex.com and have been modified for 2010, the pages work properly). These pages have a kind of hierarchy. So i want to add them to the sitemap. 
When being on the "AddRole" page, the breadcrumb should change to:
SiteCollectionName > Settings > Users > new Role

This works perfectly when i use the application.master (2007 controls).
But when i use the applicationv4.master (2010 controls) i do not see the breadcrumb modifieing.

Screenshot using the application.master
[image: Application.master breadcrumb]

Screenshot using the applicationv4.master
[image: Applicationv4.master breadcrumb]

Is there anyone who can explain this behavior? I am guessing the 2010 breadcrumb doesnt use the changes made in the layouts.sitemap (in the 14\templates\layouts folder )...
Is there anyway to modify this breadcrumb ?

This are my additions to the sitemap, they are added under the settings.
http://pastie.org/1354996

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem, [see this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5243/dynamic-code-based-breadcrumbs-are-not-working-in-sharepoint-2010).

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint 2010, what looks like the breadcrumb navigation is actually the title area, and it has to be hard coded in your application page.  The breadcrumbs in SharePoint 2010 are actually under the 'Navigate Up' control (folder icon).  The PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb section also needs to be overridden on your application page for this to read from the layouts.sitemap file.

I've posted all of the code changes required on my blog:
http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/adding-breadcrumb-navigation-to-sharepoint-2010-application-pages/